# Directory name must not be empty

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando laravel 8, y tengo que descargar unos archivos comprimidos en zip, que se encuentran en el disco duro D del computador.

Tengo un codigo que me descarga un archivo zip, a partir de una carpeta que se encuentra en la carpeta public, y funciona.
pero desde el disco duro D, me presenta error.

Este es el codigo que funciona:

```
public function descargar(Request $request)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $fileName = "myZip.zip";
        if($zip->open(public_path($fileName),ZipArchive::CREATE)==TRUE)
        {
            $files = File::files(public_path('myfiles'));
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
               $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
               $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
        }
        $zip->close();

        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
```

cuando lo modifico para que me obtenga los archivos de una carpeta del disco duro D:

```
public function descargar(Request $request)
    {
        $programa = '001';

        $ruta= 'CARPETA1\\SUBCARPETA\\FOTOS\\' ;

        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $fileName = $programa.".zip"; 

        if($zip->open(public_path($fileName),ZipArchive::CREATE)==TRUE)
        {
            $files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->get($ruta));
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
               $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
               $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
        }
        $zip->close();

        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
```

Me regresa el error:

> RuntimeException Directory name must not be empty.

pero cuando voy a: CARPETA1\SUBCARPETA\FOTOS\ veo que si tiene archivos, tiene justo los mismos archivos que uso en la carpeta public.

creo que en este punto algo estoy haciendo mal, talvez no debo llamarlo con get. pero no sabria que otro usar.

```
$files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->get($ruta));
```

Si antepongo el codigo:

```
if(Storage::disk('partitionD')->exists($ruta)){
                return "ruta existe";
            }
```

y ejecuto, efectivamente me imprime  "ruta existe",

en $ruta elimine los ultimos '\' y me quedó asi:

```
$ruta= 'CARPETA1\\SUBCARPETA\\FOTOS' ;
```

me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

el error se genera en esta linea:

```
$files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->get($ruta));
```

tal vez despues de disk() no debo usar el get(), si no otra cosa, pero no sabria.
Muchas gracias.

actualizacion..............................

Cuando ejecuto, $files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta));

este encuentra la primer foto, y me dice que ese directorio no existe, claro no existe por que toma el primer archivo como un directorio, el error es asi:

The "CARPETA1/SUBCARPETA/FOTOSS/1.jpg" directory does not exist.

entonces la ruta esta bien, lo que esta mal es la manera en que la llamo.
que no seria ('partitionD')->get,, ni tampoco ('partitionD')->files, debe ser otra la manera de llamarla.

Actualizacion 2..............................
Cambiando los files de esto:

```
$files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta));
a esto:
$files = Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta);
```

El proceso es capaz de continuar. pero ahora, no descarga ningun archivo dentro del zip.

cuando imprimo $files, en el codigo original me muestra algo como esto:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo {#1481 ▼
    -relativePath: ""
    -relativePathname: "1.JPG"
    path: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles"
    filename: "1.JPG"
    basename: "1.JPG"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
    extension: "JPG"
    realPath: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
    aTime: 2021-05-18 22:12:13
    mTime: 2021-04-27 16:11:02
    cTime: 2021-05-14 18:54:00
    inode: 0
    size: 63290
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
  }
]
```

con el nuevo codigo, del disco D:

```
$files = Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta);
```

Me imprime algo como esto:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "CARPETA1/SUBCARPETA/FOTOS/1.JPG"
]
```

dentro del

```
 foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
               $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
               $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
```

el $relativeNameInZipFile y el $value en el codigo original me imprime asi:

```
    "1.JPG"   y

Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo {#1481 ▼
  -relativePath: ""
  -relativePathname: "1.JPG"
  path: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles"
  filename: "1.JPG"
  basename: "1.JPG"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
  extension: "JPG"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
  aTime: 2021-05-18 22:14:24
  mTime: 2021-04-27 16:11:02
  cTime: 2021-05-14 18:54:00
  inode: 0
  size: 63290
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\myfiles\1.JPG"
}
```

y en el codigo nuevo me imprimen las dos variables asi:

"1.JPG"  y

"CARPETA1/SUBCARPETA/FOTOS/1.JPG"

La diferencia esta en $value, y tal vez esto sea lo que haga que no se guarde la foto, en el archivo zip.

Comment: cuando agrego la condicional

if(Storage::disk('partitionD')->exists($ruta)){
                return "ruta existe";
            }
este me imprime   "ruta existe", la ruta esta ok.

Comment: Y qué te devuelve en $files? Puedes hacer un `print_r($files)`?

Comment: Si elimino, '\\', sigue saliendo el mismo error.
Si le doy imprimir $files,, con dd, o con print_r($files), no me imprime, ya que la linea donde se genera el error es ahi en files, por lo tanto no continua a la siguiente linea.

siempre me marca el error: Directory name must not be empty.

Comment: Obtienes lo mismo si intentas con esto? `$files = Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta);`

Comment: Cuando ejecuto, $files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->files($ruta));

este encuentra la primer foto, y me dice que ese directorio no existe, claro no existe por que toma el primer archivo como un directorio, el error es asi:

The "CARPETA1/SUBCARPETA/FOTOSS/1.jpg" directory does not exist.

Comment: No dije que uses `File::files`. Puse directamente `Storage::disk`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, avanzó, parece ser que esa linea, a encontrado los files, y ahora es capaz de continuar, pero a diferencia del codigo que funciona, esta vez me dice que el archivo .zip en el directorio public no existe, pero el deberia ser capaz de crearlo como en el archivo original:

The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\001.zip" does not exist

Comment: Te aconsejaría utilizar directamente `/` en lugar de \\

Comment: cambié la ruta ' \'  por ' /', funciona igual, muchas gracias.
con respecto al zip.
Me creé el archivp zip. manualmente, y no genera ningun error. pero cuando veo el archivo, este no contiene ningun archivo interno. voy hacer una actualizacion en la pregunta principal, donde se muestra que contenia antes el arhivo files, y que contiene ahora.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124412/discussion-between-jonatan-lavado-and-wil).

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos los que me brindaron su ayuda, tuve muchas ideas y finalmente como sospechaba, de que estaba llamando Storage::disk  con get, y luego con files,
y que de alguna manera no era la forma correcta, encontré la forma correcta de llamarlos.
para que tuviera todas las caracteristicas del codigo original.

y la forma corecta de llamarlo seria con path.
quedando asi el codigo y funcionando sin errores:

```
if($zip->open(public_path($fileName),ZipArchive::CREATE== TRUE))
        {
            $files = File::files(Storage::disk('partitionD')->path($ruta));

            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
               $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
               $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }
        }
```

gracias totales.